# Spring Boot OAuth2 provider database tables explained

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to implement an OAuth2 server with JWT and Spring Boot 2. There are some good examples on the internet, like [this](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt) or [this](https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-boot-security-oauth2-example). They are using some database tables (`oauth_client_details`, `oauth_client_token`, `oauth_code`, `oauth_approvals`, `ClientDetails`) with a bunch of fields. Some of them are easy to understand, others are not. I couldn't find anywhere an explanation on what tables and fields are required and what they mean:

---

```
create table oauth_client_details (      /*Stores client details*/
  client_id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
  resource_ids VARCHAR(255),             /*Q1: is this comma separated list of resources?*/
  client_secret VARCHAR(255),
  scope VARCHAR(255),
  authorized_grant_types VARCHAR(255),
  web_server_redirect_uri VARCHAR(255),
  authorities VARCHAR(255),              /*Q2: what it this for?*/
  access_token_validity INTEGER,         /*Q3: Is this the validity period in seconds?*/
  refresh_token_validity INTEGER,
  additional_information VARCHAR(4096),  /*Q4: Can I omit this field if I don't need any additional information?*/
  autoapprove VARCHAR(255)               /*Q5: What does this mean?*/
);  

create table if not exists oauth_client_token ( /*Q6: What is this table for?*/
  token_id VARCHAR(255),
  token LONGVARBINARY,
  authentication_id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
  user_name VARCHAR(255),
  client_id VARCHAR(255)
);  

create table if not exists oauth_access_token ( /*Q7: Do I need this table if I use JWT?*/
  token_id VARCHAR(255),
  token LONGVARBINARY,
  authentication_id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
  user_name VARCHAR(255),
  client_id VARCHAR(255),
  authentication LONGVARBINARY,
  refresh_token VARCHAR(255)
);  

create table if not exists oauth_refresh_token ( /*Q8: Do I need this table if I use JWT?*/
  token_id VARCHAR(255),
  token LONGVARBINARY,
  authentication LONGVARBINARY
);  

create table if not exists oauth_code (
  code VARCHAR(255), authentication LONGVARBINARY
);  

create table if not exists oauth_approvals ( /*Q9: What it this for?*/
  userId VARCHAR(255),
  clientId VARCHAR(255),
  scope VARCHAR(255),
  status VARCHAR(10),
  expiresAt TIMESTAMP,
  lastModifiedAt TIMESTAMP
);  

create table if not exists ClientDetails ( /*Q10: Yet another client details???*/
  appId VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
  resourceIds VARCHAR(255),
  appSecret VARCHAR(255),
  scope VARCHAR(255),
  grantTypes VARCHAR(255),
  redirectUrl VARCHAR(255),
  authorities VARCHAR(255),
  access_token_validity INTEGER,
  refresh_token_validity INTEGER,
  additionalInformation VARCHAR(4096),
  autoApproveScopes VARCHAR(255)
);
```

---

Comment: I am also looking for some explanations. Is there any official docs for the above schema from Spring? I searched and couldn't find any. Can anybody help?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find any official docs from Spring, I don't believe it exists.

Answer (score 6):

In case of JWT token, there is no need for `oauth_access_token` & `oauth_refresh_token` tables. check implementation of `JwtTokenStore` for more info.

Which tables are necessary, totally depends on [OAuth Grant type](https://alexbilbie.com/guide-to-oauth-2-grants/) you are using. Tables like `oauth_code` & `oauth_approvals` will be required if you are using `Authorization code` grant type.

different between `scope` and `authorities`, check [OAuth Scope vs Authorities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32092749/spring-oauth2-scope-vs-authoritiesroles)

Answer (score 3):

Here are some answers for the questions which are not answered.

Q4 : Yes, you can omit

Q7 , Q8 : No need of oauth_access_token, oauth_refresh_token tables if use jwt,

when a token is requested from the client, the access token and relevant details are stored in the oauth_access_token table. the details about this token is removed after the validity seconds expired. 
The oauth_refresh_token table stores details of refresh token. after the access token get expired, you can use this refresh token to achieve a new access token

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I, unfortunately, can't answer all of your questions, but I can answer some at least:

Q1: Yes it is a comma-separated list.
Q3: Yes that's right.

Several tables are only needed with certain authorization grant types, as Afridi already mentioned in his answer. I found this particular [page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) pretty helpful in understanding how which grant-type works and what tables I might need for it.

Q10: I don't think that you need that table.

Answer (score 0):

- Q1: Yes
- Q2: N/A
- Q3: Yes
- Q4: Yes. Note: `oauth_client_details` supports for `JdbcClientDetailsService`. You can create your `ClientDetailsService` implementation with your customized table.
- Q5: Client scopes which are automatically approved by authorization
  server, supports for Authorization Code flow
- Q6: This table is used by `JdbcClientTokenServices`
- Q7: Yes, this table supports for `JwtTokenStore`
- Q8: Yes, this table supports for `JwtTokenStore`
- Q9: Store approval status, supports for Authorization Code flow
- Q10: Just a customized `oauth_client_details` if you want